# Match and Replace between dataframes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes `Full Table` and `Dataset`, the first one has `Key_Identifier` `Accesion` and `Sequence` columns while the other has only my data of interest with `Accesion` and `Sequence` columns.

## What I Have

in `Full Table`:

```
Key_Identifier Accesion Sequence
ARG1 AA001 AAACTGGG
ARG2 AA002 AAACTGGC
ARS2 AA003 AAACTGGG
ART1 AA004 AAACTGGA
ARG3 AA005 AAACTGCG
ART4 AA006 AAACTGGG
```

and in `Dataset`:

```
Accesion Sequence
AA001 ACTGGG
AA003 ACTGGG
AA005 ACTGCG
AA006 ACTGGG
```

## What I Want

I want to match `Accesion` from `Dataset` in `Full Table` and replace its name to `Key_Identifer` from `Full Table` keeping `Sequence` intact in `Dataset`. Like:

```
Accesion Sequence
ARG1 ACTGGG
ARS2 ACTGGG
ARG3 ACTGCG
ART4 ACTGGG
```

which is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can merge using merge(a, b, by.x = 'key_identifier', by.y = 'accesion')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dplyr/the tidyverse works well for this since it's pretty intuitive for new R users. You can get rid of columns you don't care about with `select(-col_to_delete)`, then `inner_join` to get just the rows where there's a match. From there it's a simple case of removing the extra column and renaming as needed:

```
Full_Table %>% 
  select(-Sequence) %>% 
  inner_join(
    Dataset,
    by = "Accesion"
  ) %>% 
  select(-Accesion) %>% 
  rename(
    Accesion = Key_Identifier
  )
```

For your simple example, I imagine `merge` from base R is sufficient, but if you are doing more complex transformations, definitely look into dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/merge.html) to merge two data frames. Since column names are different this can be handled by `by.x = 'key_identifier', by.y = 'accesion'`.

```
a <- data.frame('key_identifier' = c('AAA001', 'AAA003', 'AAA005'),  'accesion'= c('ARG1', 'ARG2', 'ARS2'), 'sequence' = c('AAACTGGG', 'AAACTGGC', 'AAACTGGG'))
b <- data.frame('accesion' = c('AAA001', 'AAA003', 'AAA005'), 'sequence' = c('ACTGGG', 'ACTGGG', 'ACTGCG'))
c <- merge(a, b, by.x = 'key_identifier', by.y = 'accesion')

 key_identifier accesion sequence.x sequence.y
1         AAA001     ARG1   AAACTGGG     ACTGGG
2         AAA003     ARG2   AAACTGGC     ACTGGG
3         AAA005     ARS2   AAACTGGG     ACTGCG
```

Select necessary columns,

```
f <- c[,c(2,4)]
colnames(f) <- c('Accesion', 'Sequence')

Accesion Sequence
1     ARG1   ACTGGG
2     ARG2   ACTGGG
3     ARS2   ACTGCG
```